# What does compact, or non-compact closure imply about the space?

Tags: general-topology, euclidean-geometry, compactness, real-numbers

I have seen this claim when consulting some topological stuff at my university:

For $n \geq 2$, let $D \subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$ be closed and discrete and let $U \subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$ be nonempty, nonbounded, open with $\overline{U}$ non-compact. Then there exists a homeomorphism $h: \mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^n}$ such that $h(D) \subseteq U$.

You can forget about this claim, but I have some general and (I hope) interesting questions that arised from that:

1. Why we need the closure of $U$ to be non-compact? Generally, what does non-compact closure imply about the space itself?
2. Aren´t all discrete sets in $\mathbb{R^n}$ automatically closed, since their complements must be open, right?
3. Can a discrete set be mapped homeomorphicaly into a non-discrete (continuous) set?

Thank you for your insights.

Comment: Since $\mathrm{closed} + \mathrm{bounded} = \mathrm{compact}$ in Euclidean space, and since $\overline{U}$ is always closed, saying it is non-compact is just a fancy way of saying it must be unbounded.

Comment: $\{\frac1n\mid n\in\mathbb N^+\}$ is discrete but not closed in $\mathbb R.$

Comment: The property of being discrete is a topological property and is preserved by homeomorphisms. A set $D$ is discrete iff it carries the discrete topology as a subspace of our topological space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $U$ is bounded and $D$ is infinite, discrete, and closed, and we have a homeomorphism $f$ with $f(D)\subset U,$ the image, $f(D),$ would be a bounded infinite subset of $\mathbb R^n,$ so it would have to have limit points.

(A) If a limit point is not in $f(D),$ then $f(D)$ is not closed.

(B) If a limit point is in $f(D),$ then $f(D)$ is not discrete.

Show that neither of these are possible.

---

This all can be made more succinct using compactness language if you know:

> (1) A closed subset of a compact space is compact.

> (2) An infinite discrete space is not compact.

Then assume we have a homeomorphism  $f(D)\subseteq U\subseteq \overline{U}.$

If $\overline U$ is compact, then, since $f(D)$ is closed, $f(D)$ is compact. But that would mean $D$ is compact, which would require $D$ finite.

---

Other answers:

1. A subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded. If $\overline{U}$ is not bounded, then $U$ is not bounded. So the condition on $U$ can be restated as “$U$ is open and not bounded.”
2. $\{\frac1n\mid n\in\mathbb Z^+\}$ is discrete but not closed in $\mathbb R.$

---

If $D$ is finite, you don’t need the unbounded condition on $U.$ It is true for any non-empty open $U.$

In fact, if $D$ is any bounded set, discrete or not, closed or note, and $U$ is non-empty and open, there is a fairly simple homeomorphism sending $D$ to elements of $U.$

Namely, let $x_0\in U,$ and let $\epsilon>0$ be such that $N_\epsilon(x_0)\subseteq U.$

Let $r=\sup_{x\in D}\|x\|.$ This is finite if $D$ is bounded. Then we can take $$f(x)=\frac{\epsilon}{2r}x+x_0.$$

Comment: I think to show the (A), (B) is true, it is sufficient to say $f(D)$ cannot be discrete or closed, since both these properties are topological invariants. And do the last few paragraphs apply only for D finite? Because for infinite, I am not sure.