# Can an infinite bounded set containing its limit points be discrete?

Tags: general-topology, limits, intuition

**My question:** If a set is infinite and bounded and contains its limit points, does it mean it cannot be discrete? Why?

**My thoughts:** Limit point is a point that is "infinitely close" to other points. So if a set contains a limit point, other points are so close that it cannot be discrete anymore, since the points are almost "glued" together.

**Why I am asking:** Regarding an answer to [one of my previous questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4237614/what-does-compact-or-non-compact-closure-imply-about-the-space/4237623#4237623): . There, Thomas Andrews made an implication that if the infinite and bounded set $F(D)$ has limit points inside it, then it cannot be discrete. [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4237614/what-does-compact-or-non-compact-closure-imply-about-the-space/4237623#4237623)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a set $S$ has a point $x$ which is a limit point of $S$, then every neighborhood of $x$ has a point $s\in S$ with $s\ne x$ (from the definition of limit point). But if $S$ is discrete, then, for every $s\in S$, there is a neighborhood $U$ of $s$ such that $U\cap S=\{s\}$. So, indeed, a subset of a topological space containing its limit points cannot be discrete.

Comment: Yes. I first thought the question was about Bolzano-Weierstrass or Heine-Borel, but that is not really what the question is about.